# Can I prove that (forall x. Coercible (a x) (b x)) implies Coercible a b?

Tags: haskell, coercion

I'm manipulating proofs of coercibility:

```hs
data a ~=~ b where
  IsCoercible :: Coercible a b => a ~=~ b
infix 0 ~=~

sym :: (a ~=~ b) -> (b ~=~ a)
sym IsCoercible = IsCoercible

instance Category (~=~) where 
  id = IsCoercible
  IsCoercible . IsCoercible = IsCoercible

coerceBy :: a ~=~ b -> a -> b
coerceBy IsCoercible = coerce
```

I can trivially prove `Coercible a b => forall x. Coercible (a x) (b x)`

```hs
introduce :: (a ~=~ b) -> (forall x. a x ~=~ b x)
introduce IsCoercible = IsCoercible
```

But not the converse, `(forall x. Coercible (a x) (b x)) => Coercible a b)` isn't quite as free:

```hs
eliminate :: (forall x. a x ~=~ b x) -> (a ~=~ b)
eliminate IsCoercible = IsCoercible
{-
   • Could not deduce: Coercible a b
        arising from a use of ‘IsCoercible’
      from the context: Coercible (a x0) (b x0)
        bound by a pattern with constructor:
                   IsCoercible :: forall k (a :: k) (b :: k).
                                  Coercible a b =>
                                  a ~=~ b,
                 in an equation for ‘eliminate’
-}
```

I'm fairly certain my claim is valid (though I'm open to being disproven), but I'm not having any bright ideas as to how to prove it within Haskell short of `unsafeCoerce`.

Comment: In other words... you're asking if Haskell type-level functions satisfy functional extensionality...

Comment: It's possible for a claim to be neither provable or disprovable. The axiom `forall a b. (forall x. a x ~=~ b x) -> a ~=~ b` is very likely *consistent* with the type system (not disprovable; nothing goes wrong if you admit it with `unsafeCoerce`), but it's probably not provable.

Comment: [Safe Zero-cost Coercions for Haskell](https://repository.brynmawr.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1005&context=compsci_pubs) has the full rules on page 6 (PDF page 7 at this link). `Co_Inst` is the only rule that applies to forall-quantified stuff, and doesn't seem particularly helpful. I suspect such a rule could be added without breaking soundness. Another conspicuously missing rule (which would also get you where you needed to go) would be one saying that if all of a data type's fields are coercible with another, the type itself is coercible with the other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't. As Dominique Devriese and HTNW hint in their comments, GHC doesn't admit that inference at all. This more demanding version won't compile:

```
{-# language QuantifiedConstraints, RankNTypes #-}

import Data.Coerce
import Data.Type.Coercion

eliminate :: (forall a. Coercible (f a) (g a)) => Coercion f g
eliminate = Coercion
```

Your version is even more doomed. To pattern match on the polymorphic `Coercion` (or `~=~`) argument, it must be instantiated to a particular type. GHC will instantiate it to `f Any ~=~ g Any`, which is then monomorphic and therefore doesn't prove what you want it to. Since GHC Core is typed, that won't fly.

Side note: I find it intensely frustrating that there's no way to write

```
f :: (forall a. c a :- d a)
  -> ((forall a. c a => d a) => r)
  -> r
```

Comment: Oh hey, `Data.Type.Coercion` obviates the need for `(~=~)`, and is in `base`! handy

Comment: I'm currently cheating with [`eliminate = unsafeCoerce`](https://github.com/rampion/concrete-kinds/blob/8c19de87500d0cf63cd64cf95c9b094d01fc8ab9/src/Data/Type/Coercion.hs#L22), since `Coercible` is implemented as an empty dictionary. It [hasn't kicked up any errors in testing yet](https://github.com/rampion/concrete-kinds/blob/8c19de87500d0cf63cd64cf95c9b094d01fc8ab9/src/Data/Type/Coercion/Test.hs), so I'm cautiously optimistic,